# Zero of holomorphic functions: the function $f(z)=\sin \frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I've learned a theorem that says that the zeroes of a holomorphic function are isolated. But consider the function $f(z)=\sin \frac{1}{z}$, defined on $\Omega=D\setminus\{0\}$, where $D$ is unit disc. So $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$. Does this contradict the theorem？Thanks for your help！

Comment: Thank you~@KennyWong